# How to order by a inner join tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables. here's my code

```sql
SELECT * FROM reservation AS t1 INNER JOIN guest AS t2
ON t1.guest_id = t2.guest_id 
INNER JOIN room AS t3 
ON t1.room_id = t3.room_id 
INNER JOIN room_type AS t4
ON t3.room_type_id = t4.room_type_id
```

How can i order by this in desc? thanks a lot :)

[image]

Comment: Uhh... just do `ORDER BY` what is the issue? Have you ever tried it?

Comment: yea it doesnt work :(

Comment: @dadadaxtr can you paste the error you are getting?

Comment: @R.DarioDuarte there is no error sir..

Comment: but the order by sorting not functioning

Comment: just 'order by desc' on the column you want ordered

Comment: @RyanGadsdon how to query my column that i want to sort is. t1.reservation_datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM reservation AS t1 INNER JOIN guest AS t2
ON t1.guest_id = t2.guest_id 
INNER JOIN room AS t3 
ON t1.room_id = t3.room_id 
INNER JOIN room_type AS t4
ON t3.room_type_id = t4.room_type_id 
order by t1.guest_id desc
```

Comment: same as what i did sir.. but the column i want to sort is t1.reservation_datetime

Comment: is it possible that my table sorting affects the sorting in my query?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM reservation AS t1 INNER JOIN guest AS t2
 ON t1.guest_id = t2.guest_id 
 INNER JOIN room AS t3 
 ON t1.room_id = t3.room_id 
 INNER JOIN room_type AS t4
 ON t3.room_type_id = t4.room_type_id
 ORDER BY t1.reservation_datetime DESC
```

This would be what you're asking but where does this column come from?

Comment: from the reservation.. i use that already.. i guest my table sorting affects my query.

Comment: @dadadaxtr post your table structures and then we can help more

Comment: @dadadaxtr what do your current results look like?

Comment: Thanks all for help.. the problem is my table automatic sorting.. i disabled it already and my query works ;) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you just need to add the `ORDER BY DESC [COLUMN]`.

That should fix your issue.

```sql
SELECT * FROM reservation AS t1
INNER JOIN guest AS t2
ON t1.guest_id = t2.guest_id 
INNER JOIN room AS t3 
ON t1.room_id = t3.room_id 
INNER JOIN room_type AS t4
ON t3.room_type_id = t4.room_type_id
ORDER BY t1.reservation_datetime DESC
```

I would recommend that you name your variables in a more mnemotechnic way, I will be much easier to analyze, saying `SELECT * FROM reservation AS r`

Comment: Thanks all for help.. the problem is my table automatic sorting.. i disabled it already and my query works ;) thanks a lot!

Comment: @dadadaxtr No problem, should be sure you post all the details for your questions, so people can answer accurately. And please be sure to mark an answer as resolved, since besides you had another problem, the answers were correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM reservation AS t1 
INNER JOIN guest AS t2 ON t1.guest_id = t2.guest_id 
INNER JOIN room AS t3 ON t1.room_id = t3.room_id 
INNER JOIN room_type AS t4 ON t3.room_type_id = t4.room_type_id
ORDER BY t1.reservation_datetime DESC
```

but make sure

- there must be the column name reservation_datetime in reservation table
- guest_id column should be present in reservation table and guest table
- room_id column must be exist in room table and reservation table
- room_type_id column must be exist in room table and room_type table

Comment: it all exist.. base on your statement. maybe may table is the problem.. it sort automatically.

Comment: try by applying order by other than datetime column like t1.reservation_id.

Comment: Thanks all for help.. the problem is my table automatic sorting.. i disabled it already and my query works ;) thanks a lot!